# Statically built FFMPEG binary segmentation fault

Tags: c++, c, gcc, ffmpeg, static-libraries

I want to create a custom build of FFMPEG which rips out everything except for the ability to transmux HLS videos to MP4, and I need this build to be 100% static with no external dependencies

I tried using the following configuration:

```
./configure \
    --extra-cflags='-static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' \
    --extra-cxxflags='-static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' \
    --extra-ldflags='-static -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc' \
    --pkg-config-flags='--static' \
    --enable-static \
    --disable-shared \
    --disable-runtime-cpudetect \
    --disable-autodetect \
    --disable-ffplay \
    --disable-ffprobe \
    --disable-doc \
    --disable-avdevice \
    --disable-swresample \
    --disable-swscale \
    --disable-postproc \
    --disable-pthreads \
    --disable-w32threads \
    --disable-os2threads \
    --enable-network \
    --disable-dct \
    --disable-dwt \
    --disable-error-resilience \
    --disable-lsp \
    --disable-lzo \
    --disable-mdct \
    --disable-rdft \
    --disable-fft \
    --disable-faan \
    --disable-pixelutils \
    --disable-encoders \
    --disable-decoders \
    --disable-hwaccels \
    --disable-muxers \
    --enable-muxer=mov \
    --enable-muxer=mp4 \
    --disable-demuxers \
    --enable-demuxer=hls \
    --enable-demuxer=mpegts \
    --enable-demuxer=h264 \
    --enable-demuxer=aac \
    --disable-parsers \
    --enable-parser=h264 \
    --enable-parser=aac \
    --disable-bsfs \
    --disable-protocols \
    --enable-protocol=tcp \
    --enable-protocol=tls \
    --enable-protocol=http \
    --enable-protocol=https \
    --enable-protocol=hls \
    --disable-indevs \
    --disable-outdevs \
    --disable-devices \
    --disable-filters \
    --disable-alsa \
    --disable-appkit \
    --disable-avfoundation \
    --disable-bzlib \
    --disable-coreimage \
    --disable-iconv \
    --disable-lzma \
    --enable-openssl \
    --disable-sndio \
    --disable-sdl2 \
    --disable-securetransport \
    --disable-xlib \
    --disable-zlib \
    --disable-amf \
    --disable-audiotoolbox \
    --disable-cuda-llvm \
    --disable-cuvid \
    --disable-d3d11va \
    --disable-dxva2 \
    --disable-ffnvcodec \
    --disable-nvdec \
    --disable-nvenc \
    --disable-v4l2-m2m \
    --disable-vaapi \
    --disable-vdpau \
    --disable-videotoolbox \
    --disable-debug
```

This looked about like what I wanted:

```
install prefix            /usr/local
source path               .
C compiler                gcc
C library                 glibc
ARCH                      x86 (generic)
big-endian                no
runtime cpu detection     no
standalone assembly       yes
x86 assembler             nasm
MMX enabled               yes
MMXEXT enabled            yes
3DNow! enabled            yes
3DNow! extended enabled   yes
SSE enabled               yes
SSSE3 enabled             yes
AESNI enabled             yes
AVX enabled               yes
AVX2 enabled              yes
AVX-512 enabled           yes
XOP enabled               yes
FMA3 enabled              yes
FMA4 enabled              yes
i686 features enabled     yes
CMOV is fast              yes
EBX available             yes
EBP available             yes
debug symbols             no
strip symbols             yes
optimize for size         no
optimizations             yes
static                    yes
shared                    no
postprocessing support    no
network support           yes
threading support         no
safe bitstream reader     yes
texi2html enabled         no
perl enabled              yes
pod2man enabled           yes
makeinfo enabled          no
makeinfo supports HTML    no

External libraries:
openssl

External libraries providing hardware acceleration:

Libraries:
avcodec                 avfilter                avformat                avutil

Programs:
ffmpeg

Enabled decoders:

Enabled encoders:

Enabled hwaccels:

Enabled parsers:
aac                     h264

Enabled demuxers:
aac                     h264                    hls                     mpegts

Enabled muxers:
mov                     mp4

Enabled protocols:
hls                     http                    https                   tcp                     tls

Enabled filters:
aformat                 anull                   atrim                   format                  hflip                   null                    transpose               trim                    vflip

Enabled bsfs:
null

Enabled indevs:

Enabled outdevs:

License: LGPL version 2.1 or later
```

It included several filters which I won't ever need or use, but these filters are pulled in automatically if you don't specify `--disable-avfilter`, and specifying `--disable-avfilter` prevents the `ffmpeg` binary from being produced. So I'm stuck with those.

Using these parameters and then running `make`, I received a binary that was about 5.9 MB in size and ***looked*** right:

```
$> ldd ffmpeg
        not a dynamic executable
```

But when I try to run it:

```
$> ./ffmpeg -version
Segmentation fault
```

Using valgrind to try and inspect the cause of the segmentation fault:

```
$> valgrind ./ffmpeg -version
.... lots of stuff ...
==61362== Jump to the invalid address stated on the next line
==61362==    at 0x0: ???
==61362==    by 0x70BB1B: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x70B2E6: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x4033F9: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x1FFF000677: ???
==61362==  Address 0x0 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==61362==
==61362==
==61362== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==61362==  Bad permissions for mapped region at address 0x0
==61362==    at 0x0: ???
==61362==    by 0x70BB1B: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x70B2E6: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x4033F9: ??? (in /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg)
==61362==    by 0x1FFF000677: ???
==61362==
==61362== HEAP SUMMARY:
==61362==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==61362==   total heap usage: 0 allocs, 0 frees, 0 bytes allocated
==61362==
==61362== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==61362==
==61362== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==61362== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==61362== ERROR SUMMARY: 93 errors from 90 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
Segmentation fault
```

Attempting to access memory at location `0x0` ***sounds like*** trying to follow a null pointer. But I'm not sure how to fix this.

### gdb backtrace

When I first ran `gdb ./ffmpeg` gdb immediately gave me a segmentation fault and I wasn't kicked into the gdb REPL, so I couldn't investigate

After rebuilding ffmpeg I was able to get in this time:

```
$> gdb ./ffmpeg

GNU gdb (Ubuntu 8.1-0ubuntu3.2) 8.1.0.20180409-git
Copyright (C) 2018 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from ffmpeg...done.
(gdb) r
Starting program: /src/FFmpeg/ffmpeg
warning: Error disabling address space randomization: Operation not permitted

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000000f9a8d5 in __register_frame_info_bases.part.6 ()
#2  0x00000000004445fd in frame_dummy ()
#3  0x0000000000000001 in ?? ()
#4  0x0000000000ebd20c in __libc_csu_init ()
#5  0x0000000000ebc9d7 in __libc_start_main ()
#6  0x000000000044451a in _start ()
(gdb)
```

I tried grep'ing the code base for `__register_frame_info_bases` and found nothing. So I'm not really sure where to go from here

### A fix, but not an explanation

By randomly removing configuration parameters and rebuilding I discovered that `--disable-pthreads` was causing the segmentation fault. When I remove this, ffmpeg runs just fine

I don't know ***why*** this is the case, though. Why would they make it possible to remove something that you need to run?

Comment: Try building with debug flags, running in gdb, and getting a backtrace when it segfaults to see where the offending code lies.  Read through the source to see how you arrived there.  Maybe run it through some static analysis tools and see if they spot anything.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons How do I load a program into gdb? When I try `gdb ./ffmpeg` it immediately seg faults without giving me an opportunity to set break points or anything

Comment: That's fine if it segfaults.  You can get a backtrace from the point that it segfaulted and take a look at the state of the different frames in the call-stack to figure out what happened.

Comment: I think you misunderstand. After the message `Segmentation fault` is printed, I'm not inside the gdb REPL. I'm kicked back to bash.

Comment: Can you debug a simple test program in `gdb`? What is your OS?

Comment: You should not use `--disable-debug` if you need to debug and maybe there is explicit `--enable-debug`. Then corresponding source files with line numbers should be displayed in debugger/crash dump analyzer stack trace.

Comment: @Bodo My host OS is Mac OS X, but I'm doing all of this inside a Ubuntu Docker container

Comment: @dewaffled I removed `--disable-debug` and added `--disable-stripping` before attempting my gdb run. It was almost as if gdb itself seg faulted, because I wasn't dropped into a REPL.

Comment: @stevendesu Please [edit] your question and add all information there. Does debugging a simple program work?

Comment: @Bodo I'll work on updating the question once I rebuild ffmpeg. While waiting on answers I was messing around with random configuration options and discovered that removing `--disable-pthreads` fixed the segmentation fault. I guess something in the FFMPEG source expects this library to exist, even though they allow you to disable it

Comment: Sounds like this would be better as an ffmpeg bug report than as a StackOverflow question.

Comment: @NateEldredge I agree, but it started as a StackOverflow question. Discovery of the bug came after investigating the problem.